# Fetching value from the database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a mysql table named 'customer'. serialnumber (int), name(varchar), gender(varchar) are the table fields.

I have a int variable a = 2.

I want to fetch the value from the table when serialnumber = a. That is when the serialnumber = 2 it should display the particular customer's name.

```
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/shopping";
String usr ="root";
String pass = "rootpassword";

session.setAttribute( "URL", url );
session.setAttribute( "user", usr );
session.setAttribute( "passwd", pass );

String connectionURL = (String)session.getAttribute( "URL" );
String user = (String)session.getAttribute("user");
String passwd = (String)session.getAttribute("passwd");
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, user, passwd);
      statement = connection.createStatement();

rs=statement.executeQuery("select * from customer where serialnumber like '%a%' ");

      while (rs.next()) {
      out.println("Customer Name: ");
      out.println(rs.getString("name")); 
     }rs.close();
    }catch(Exception ce){out.println(ce);}
```

This throws me nothing. But when i give the number instead a in rs.execute Query it displays the customer name. How to solve this and what is my mistake??

Thanks

Comment: And why are you using `LIKE` when you want to test equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating `a` like a literal, instead of a variable.  You will need to update the query like this:

```
executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE serialnumber LIKE '%" + a + "%' ");
```

I did not include `rs = statement.` for brevity, and to remove the scrolling.  You will still need it for your solution.

---

@ypercube makes a good point: If you are looking to see when the serialnumber is exactly 2:

```
rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE serialnumber = " + a);
```

---

Also, if you're only using the `name` field, you shouldn't `SELECT *` but instead `SELECT name`

Comment: Yeah, it was my bad not declare a as how it should be. I updated my query as you said and it worked just fine. Regarding the value of 'a' it is not fixed. it changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that **LIKE** is appropriate to an integer column, even if it work.
Here a more formal/efficent/secure version:

```
String selectString = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE serialnumber = ?";
selectStm = connection.prepareStatement(selectString);
selectStm.setInt(1, a.intValue());
rs = selectStm.executeQuery();
```